# Максимальная сумма в двумерном списке

Tags: алгоритм

Подскажите алгоритм для решения задачи:

Есть двумерный список (таблица).
Нужно от левого верхнего угла добраться до правого нижнего и значения (через которые мы перемещаемся) нужно складывать.

Но задача в том, что нужно определить максимально возможное такое суммарное число.
Можно перемещаться либо вниз, либо направо (сколько угодно раз, лишь бы в итоге было максимальное суммарное число).
Например дана такая таблица:

```
listt = [[2, 7, 8, 0],
         [2, 1, 1, 3],
         [0, 3, 12, 2],
         [2, 1, 5, 4]]
```

После обхода самая максимальная сумма равна 39 (т.е. 2, 7, 8, 1, 12, 5, 4)
Какой здесь алгоритм нахождения максимальной суммы?
Нужно каждый элемент сравнивать с предыдущими со всеми возможными?
А если массив будет намного больше, как тогда решать?
**P.S. как это реализовать без использования методов, просто циклом и условным оператором?**

Comment: Почитайте про динамическое программирование, самое базовое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм очень простой: в каждую ячейку (новой матрицы) записывать сумму числа в этой ячейки и максимального из двух чисел сверху и слева от неё.

Уточнение:  не тех чисел, которые в матрице изначально,  а постепенно, начиная с левого верхнего угла. Т.о. в каждой ячейке будет максимально возможная сумма.

Т. е.  в результате вторая матрица получится такая:

```
listt = [[2, 9, 17, 17],
         [4, 10, 18, 21],
         [4, 13, 30, 32],
         [6, 14, 35, 39]]
```

В итоге справа внизу получается необходимый результат.

Comment: а если нету левой или верхней ячейки?

Comment: @GGO значит, соответствующее значение равно нулю. Очевидно же.

Comment: Да? А если бы минимум искали, также очевидно было?)

Comment: Или если бы отрицательные значения в матрице были бы.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов а если завтра метеорит упадёт? Причём тут минимум вообще? Отрицательные числа ни на что не влияют.

Comment: Ну, представьте себе такую ситуацию [[1,-2, 3], [4,5,6]], и мы в какой-то момент там ищем максимум для 3 по ДП, тогда получится: 3 + max(0, -2) = 3. И у вас все сломается.

Comment: Метеориты чаще падают, чем вы думаете.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов а, ну так да. Я в своё время первый ряд и первую колонку просто кумулятивно сложил, так что не имело значения.